# Linking static library with gnu g++, No such file or directory

Tags: c++, static, linker, gnu

I'm writing a software that depends on the [Poco c++ library](http://www.pocoproject.org). I can manage to compile the library on both Ubuntu and Windows, but only as static. That's fine since I want to use it statically. However, when I try to compile the program that depends on the libraries, I get an error similar to this (freely translated) :

```
Poco/RegularExpression.h: No such file or directory.
```

However, when I also explicitly tells the compiler where to look for the library's header files with the -I switch I get the following error instead (but maybe 20-30 similar lines) :

```
Undefined reference to (pthread_mutex...)
```

I've tried with a lot of different combinations, both directly with g++, and by using makefiles.
Am I supposed to include the paths to the libraries' header files, or have I somehow not succeeded to compile the libraries properly?
If I should include the paths, how can I get rid of the "undefined reference" error?

I'm pretty new with c++ programming so bear with me.
Thanks, Robert

Comment: Maybe try adding `-lpthread`. Looks like that library is missing in the linking stage.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, to compile a simple test. But is this the correcct way to link and include the headers?

Comment: No idea what you mean by "the correct way", but yes, in general you have to specify the include directories for all headers that you include like `<this>`, and you have to link against all libraries that you are using (or that other libraries that you are using are using, recursively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very common error, I, too, suffer from it every now and then.

- Did you include the .a to your project?
- How do you include the headers? with <> or ""?

  - If the latter, make sure the files are in your include folder.
  - If first, make sure you have added the path to the files, or that they reside in g++'s global include folder
- Is the library meant to be compiled as .so/.dll?

  - Normally if the library is meant to be dynamic, the static library only points to it.
- Do you have included the dependencies the Poco itself requires? Like the -lpthread I think you are missing.

Comment: "The .a" and "as .so/.dll" is a bit slangy; a bit like when you say "I need new bridgestones" or "I lost my Dolce".  I'd propose static library or just library ;)

Comment: Thanks, that really got me going :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the `-I` option. In the target that has `RegularExpression.h` as a dependancy, try to include the directory that contains the above header file like so:

`g++ -I/home/.../Poco <other options>`